# Is there a python library for validate the swagger Yaml file?

Tags: python, api, yaml

I am currently working with automatic update swagger server. Form time to time, the swagger APIs can be changed. Each time of the changes, the python script will download the APIs and create the swagger server. However, there are some errors in the swagger Yaml file which contains the APIs.

I would like to validate this Yaml file in Python, not safe_load but based on the swagger format. The output errors can be something like "missing input parameters" that related to the swagger Yaml not only  Yaml file itself.

By the way, I have tried the [swagger-parser](https://github.com/Trax-air/swagger-parser) and it does not work. So I hope someone can help me find a better solution to the swagger yaml validation method(tool).